# Material UI ClickAwayListener close when clicking itself

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the below display sidebar Switch that shows up within a Popper. So, Ideally, if you click elsewhere (outside of the Popper element), Popper should disappear. If you click inside Popper element, it should not go anywhere. When I click on the Switch or Display Sidebar text, that Popper goes away. I wrapped the Popper with `<div>` it didn't help either.

Popper https://material-ui.com/api/popper/

Switch https://material-ui.com/api/switch/

ClickAwayListener https://material-ui.com/utils/click-away-listener/

Below is the Popper Code

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={this.handleClickAway}>
      <div>
        <Popper className={classes.popper} id={id} open={open} placement="bottom-end" anchorEl={anchorEl} transition>
          {({ TransitionProps }) => (
            <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
              <Paper className={classes.SliderBox}>
                <Switch
                  checked={this.state.checkedB}
                  onChange={this.handleChange('checkedB')}
                  value="checkedB"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={handleDrawer}
                  className={classNames(classes.menuButton, sidebar && classes.hide)}
                />
                Display Sidebar
              </Paper>
            </Fade>
          )}
        </Popper>
        </div>
       </ClickAwayListener>
```

I have the sample here (though I couldn't get it work I don't know why it gives error on clickaway)
https://codesandbox.io/s/8pkm3x1902

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces this. I suspect you should put the `ClickAwayListener` directly around the `Paper` (inside the `Fade`), but without having an easy way to try this out, I'm not certain that is the correct solution.

Comment: Okay here it is though I don't know why when I click it's giving error on clickawaylistener. https://codesandbox.io/s/8pkm3x1902

Comment: you didn't define handleClickAway(). Can you add that? @Extelliqent

Comment: Fixed, thank you, here it is. https://codesandbox.io/s/8pkm3x1902

Comment: the problem sandbox is working for me?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default, `Popper` leverages a [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/Popper/Popper.js#L202) which renders its content in a separate part of the DOM (as a direct child of the `<body>` element) from where the `Popper` element is. This means that you have the `ClickAwayListener` around an empty `<div>`, so a click anywhere (including within the Popper content) will be considered to be outside of that empty `<div>`.

Moving the `ClickAwayListener` directly around the `Fade` (rather than around the `Popper`) ensures that it is surrounding the actual content rendered by the `Popper`.

Here's a working example based on your sandbox:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";
import Fade from "@material-ui/core/Fade";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import ClickAwayListener from "@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null,
    open: false,
    checkedB: true
  };

  handleClick = (event) => {
    const { currentTarget } = event;
    this.setState((state) => ({
      anchorEl: currentTarget,
      open: !state.open
    }));
  };

  handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.checked
    });
  };

  handleClickAway = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { anchorEl, open } = this.state;
    const { handleDrawer } = this.props;
    const id = open ? "simple-popper" : null;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        asdsadsa
        <Avatar
          alt="Test"
          src="https://www.nretnil.com/avatar/LawrenceEzekielAmos.png"
          style={{ margin: "0 10px" }}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
        <div>
          <Popper
            id={id}
            open={open}
            placement="bottom-end"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            transition
          >
            {({ TransitionProps }) => (
              <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={this.handleClickAway}>
                <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
                  <Paper //className={classes.SliderBox}
                  >
                    <Switch
                      checked={this.state.checkedB}
                      onChange={this.handleChange("checkedB")}
                      value="checkedB"
                      color="primary"
                      onClick={handleDrawer}
                    />
                    Display Sidebar
                  </Paper>
                </Fade>
              </ClickAwayListener>
            )}
          </Popper>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: Edit Popper ClickAwayListener]

In v4 the `ClickAwayListener` supports recognizing that elements are within its React element tree even when they are rendered within a portal (the original question was for v3), but it is still more reliable to put the `ClickAwayListener` inside the `Popper` rather than outside to avoid the `ClickAwayListener` firing on the click to open the `Popper` which then makes it look like the `Popper` isn't working since it immediately closes (example: https://codesandbox.io/s/popper-clickawaylistener-forked-x4j0l?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: Thank you @Ryan, this worked but, Fading motion is not working. It used to open up smooth fading in and fading out during closing...

Comment: Alright I moved it right outside of Fade it works as a charm, thank you!

Comment: @Ryan Cogswell thanks a lot! That worked! Is it a bug? Maybe we should open a issue in MUI github's repository?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal No, it isn’t a bug, it was just being used improperly.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I don't understand the change you made. It seems the OP put ClickAwayListener as a parent of everything, but you made it a child. The examples on the reference use it as a parent. Can you elaborate on your solution?

Comment: @cyrf I've added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, I am having a loop of the same popper on a page, in this case on clicking on popper it closing itself. How can we handle this?

Comment: @RajithaKothapally Please create your own question with a code sandbox reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, just making the `popupOpen=false` not solved the problem. So, I have to set the anchorElement to null as well, like so

```
const handleClickAway= ()=>{
popupOpen=false;   // Here you can also use state hook, but in my case, I'm using simpe boolean variable.
setAnchorEl(null);
}
```